# Authentication in SVN

Tags: java, jsp, svn, servlets

I was trying to build a custom UI for the svn using java. Its just a simple application in which you provide the svn url in a textbox. The browser asks for username and password for authentication . And then you can browse the directory structure of SVN (for reading purpose only)

For that i opted for svnkit jars. The authentication (business logic) is pretty straightforward.

```
public static ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager = null; // currently used a static variable in the class

public List<String> myfunction(String path, String uName, String password){

   public static SVNRepository repository = 
                    SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url.toString()));

        if(authManager == null){ // initializing if the authentication is not present
        if( uName != null 
               && password != null 
                   && !uName.trim().equals("") && !password.trim().equals("") ){
                        authManager = 
                            SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(uName, password);}
}

         repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);

       // logic for fetching files/folders for the specific url
}
```

The problem is that i need to set authentication manager everytime i provide a url to the repository. Obviously i dont want to store the username and password in the session and i am not sure whether keeping the authManager object in the session is safe.

Could someone please advice a way to authenticate that could be safe from security point of view ??

Comment: It depends on the environment. In my usecase I run an application on a tomcat server which uses GenericPrincipal (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/realm/GenericPrincipal.html) which implements a getPassword()